# How can I emit a single array from a stream of observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using the NGRX platform in an angular 4 project. I'm using RXJS +5.

On init of a component, I am selecting an array of objects from my store. I want this observable to emit a single array every time data changes in my store.

I am unpacking the array just fine, but packaging the stream of observables back into a single array that emits once is causing me trouble.

I would like to do the following, but this never emits a value because the subscription never completes. To my knowledge, `toArray` only emits on completion.

```
 this.addedProducts$ = this._store.select(s=>s.order.selectedProducts)
      .flatMap(prods=>prods) //emits an observable for each product in store
      .map(prod=>prod._id) //returns the id for each product
      .toArray(); // I would like this to be an Observable<string[]>
```

Instead, I have done something like this:

```
this.addedProducts$ = this._store.select(s=>s.order.selectedProducts)
  .flatMap(prods=>prods)
  .map(prod=>prod._id)
  .scan((acc, value) => {
    acc.push(value);
    return acc;
  }, [])
```

But this emits an new array every single iteration of adding an _id to the array. I would like this observable to emit a single array with all the values in it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't sit well with me, but it does accomplish what I was looking for. I'm open to hearing different approaches.

```
this.addedProducts$ = this._store.select(s=>s.order.selectedProducts)
  .map(prods=>{return prods.map((prod)=>prod._id)});
```

Comment: Why do  you not like it ? you can just say `map( prods => prods.map(p => p.id))`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding between values over time and current values.

Please let me know, but I think this solution is enough:

```
this.addedProducts$ = this
  ._store
  .select(s=>s.order.selectedProducts)
  .map(prods =>
    prods.map(prod => prod._id)
  );
```

The first `map` is the one from `Observable`, the second one is just the javascript `map` that you can use on any array.

So in the end, everytime `s.order.selectedProducts` changes, you'll get a new array containing all the ids of those products.

---

That said, you might want to use a selector instead of doing that everywhere in your app:

```
// in some selector file, for example `products.selectors.ts`
const getSelectedProductsIds => state => state.order.selectedProducts.map(prod => prod._id);

// in every component, effect, whatever where you need to access the selected products IDs
this.addedProducts$ = this._store.select(getSelectedProductsIds);
```